# Date Of Birth stored as future date in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an issue storing Date of Birth in SQL Server.

The DOB 04/14/48 is stored as 2048-04-14 (the required value is 1948-04-14) when I convert to date function. As per the articles I read, I changed the two digit cut of date to 2030 from the default value of 2049. Now I can store it as 1948-04-14. But the date of birth of 06/13/20 is still stored as 2020-06-13 (actual value is 1920-06-13).

I don't know the what should I set the two digit cut off date to fix all these issues. I am using SQL Server 2014. I am loading the data from the flat file and the date is always in mm/dd/yy format in flat file.

Comment: And what year is `04/14/16` supposed to be?, why can't you store the whole year?

Comment: You'll just need to check the date in your insert/update statement. If it's in the future, subtract 100 years from it.

Comment: @Lamak My actual requirement is this, If the year part of DOB is >the current year, subtract 100 from the year, else just convert it to yyyy-mm-dd format. I have a lot of date fields in my database, so I can apply this only to the DOB field in my SQL tables.

Comment: You need to set it to the cut off date of your data.   If all you data is from 1900's then set it to 2000.

Comment: @Please So, you need to update the date of birth every year if it's now > than the current year?

Comment: @Paparazzi If I set it to 2000, will I get the correct DOB if the DOB is >=2000 (I mean 02/27/10 to 2010-02-27). I am just asking you because it is working fine with 1920

Comment: Not kidding 2000 will work if that is the cut off date.  Set the proper date for YOUR data.   In the question you state 20 is not working and it will not work if your cut off date is 1930.

Answer (score 1):

How about doing the conversion and then subtracting a century if needed?

```
select (case when convert(date, dob, ??) > getdate()
             then dateadd(year, -100, convert(date, dob, ??))
             else convert(date, dob, ??)
        end)
```

You could even add this as a computed column in your data, if you don't have any centenarians.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this option. It is working fine. Since I have lot of date fields in my SQL tables, I need to individually add this code. Is there any way I can set up in the database level so that I do not need to update all the date fields?

Comment: @Please . . . You'll need to update all the date fields.  You can use some built-in sps, such as `sp_MSforeachtable`.